# Is there any drawback of including all the cocoa keys in info.plist even if I don't need it

Tags: ios, ios10, phonegap, info.plist

I created a Phonegap iOS app. But it suddenly started crashing when opening the camera, I found that after iOS 10 it is required to include permission string in info.plist file.

What I think is it requires the strings just to display the message nothing else.
So if I add every possible cocoa key's string in my plist file what damage can it do.

I think it is safe to add every cocoa key in my plist so that my app will not get crashed because of the "permission message" error.

Comment: You mean you want you app to formally support features it never intended to use, am I correct?

Comment: Well, if you include all the coco keys in the info.plist file, most probably it will get rejected while submitting the app to apple AppStore. They will ask you to remove it, if you are not using it for any purpose.

Comment: @MichaelV Yes exactly.

Comment: And you can explain to Apple why you app need all of it?

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan Are you sure? Is Apple that sensitive?

Comment: @MichaelV I am working on other person's code so I don't know exactly which features needs the permission that's all. Think I am being bit lazy.

Comment: Yes, just for an example https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/181

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan Thanks for reply. I will add required permission only.